# Angular get array data

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am trying to create array of my income data (short version) but I only get one array.

#### Code

```
MyArrayData: any = [];

constructor() {}

ngOnInit() {
    this.getQuizData();
}

getQuizData() {
  for (let i = 0; i < this.quiz.choices.length; i++) {
    this.MyArrayData = [{
      'choice_seq_no': this.quiz.choices[i].seq_no,
      'choice': this.quiz.choices[i].choice,
      'is_correct': this.quiz.choices[i].is_correct,
    }];
  }
  console.log('MyArrayData: ', this.MyArrayData);
}
```

This code only gives me 1 array while my income data is include 2 arrays.

[image: one]

**How can I get all my data as arrays?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `push()` to add element to `MyArrayData` instead of using `=` to reset it every iteration

```
getQuizData() {
  for (let i = 0; i < this.quiz.choices.length; i++) {
    this.MyArrayData.push({
      'choice_seq_no': this.quiz.choices[i].seq_no,
      'choice': this.quiz.choices[i].choice,
      'is_correct': this.quiz.choices[i].is_correct,
    });
  }
  console.log('MyArrayData: ', this.MyArrayData);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this inside loop:

```
this.MyArrayData.push({
      'choice_seq_no': this.quiz.choices[i].seq_no,
      'choice': this.quiz.choices[i].choice,
      'is_correct': this.quiz.choices[i].is_correct,
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
MyArrayData: any = [];

constructor() {}

ngOnInit() {
    this.getQuizData();
}

getQuizData() {
  for (let i = 0; i < this.quiz.choices.length; i++) {
    this.MyArrayData.push({
      'choice_seq_no': this.quiz.choices[i].seq_no,
      'choice': this.quiz.choices[i].choice,
      'is_correct': this.quiz.choices[i].is_correct,
    });
  }
  console.log('MyArrayData: ', this.MyArrayData);
}
```